# Match common elements within the same dataframe and adding values if true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

This is my dataset:
[image]

How I want my result dataset:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by performing matrix multiplication between the dataframe and its transpose.

```py
df = df @ df.T
print(df)

fruit   apple  orange  kiwi  berry  cherry  grape
fruit
apple       2       0     2      1       0      2
orange      0       2     0      0       2      0
kiwi        2       0     3      1       1      3
berry       1       0     1      1       0      1
cherry      0       2     1      0       3      1
grape       2       0     3      1       1      3
```

Comment: Could you please explain why multiplication worked here? 1*1 = 1, so how did I get this result?